# Serialize then deserialize mongoose.Model instance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here's my problem:

- I have a system with two hosts: machine M1 and machine M2 each running a node.js process on the same codebase.
- On M1 I have a mongoose.Model instance (user) which I need to pass (using a REST api call) to M2. I have to have the complete instance of user on M2, ie. all data, virtuals, plugins, save() should work as expected.
- One solution is to only send user's ObjectId, then on M2 to perform a query to mongodb to fetch the full object. I don't want to do this!
- Another solution would be to serialize it using `user.toJSON()` or `user.toObject()` then send it down the wire. On M2, all I do is `new User(userObject)`.
- The problem is that when calling `.save()` on this it will interpret it as a new object and attempt an `insert()` instead of an `.update()`.
- To fix this I can set `.isNew = false` on the object, however, when updating, the delta (difference between stored model and updated values) now contains all the data and mongo complains it will not update a document's _id

Is there an elegant way to solve this using a native method or plugin ?! Am I doing it wrong?!

Answer (score 0):

It may be wrong, but you may try using `upsert()` on the created user object instead of saving it.

If you plan to use it usually, you may end up defining a new static method in your schema, like:

```
Schema.statics.createOrUpdate = function(object, callback) {
    statics.upsert(this, object, callback);
};
```

This way you can pass your user data to M2, and on M2, you can update it easily.

Comment: You're correct, this is a solution and in fact i'm doing this right now, but I was looking for a more idiomatic solution, ie. updates to be handled by `mongoose.Model.save()` method. It's just a matter of taste. 10x

Answer (score 0):

This is a late call but I faced same problem before finding out `Model.hydrate` method.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.hydrate

> Shortcut for creating a new Document from existing raw data, pre-saved
>   in the DB. The document returned has no paths marked as modified
>   initially.

So on M2 `User.hydarate(userObject)` can be used instead of `new User(userObject)` and no need to set isNew to false.